# Completing the group then add zero to missing cell

Tags: r

How to do this in R using `dplyr`. I have this table

```
Product   Week    Count
A         Wk1     2 
A         Wk2     2 
B         Wk1     3
C         Wk2     4
C         Wk3     3
```

I want the output to be this

```
Product   Week   Count
A         Wk1     2
A         Wk2     2
A         Wk3     0
B         Wk1     3
B         Wk2     0
B         Wk3     0
C         Wk1     0
C         Wk2     4
C         Wk3     3
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Where is your actual code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` package the following code will complete your missing combination allowing you to specify which value for missing combination:

```
library(tidyverse)
my_df %>%
    complete(Product,Week,fill=list(Count=0))
```

This is the result:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  Product Week  Count
  <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
1 A       Wk1    2.00
2 A       Wk2    2.00
3 A       Wk3    0   
4 B       Wk1    3.00
5 B       Wk2    0   
6 B       Wk3    0   
7 C       Wk1    0   
8 C       Wk2    4.00
9 C       Wk3    3.00
```

Comment: our R infrastructure does not support this library yet. Any other lirbary that can accomplish short like this?

Comment: `tidyr`, the function `complete` is from `tidyr`

Comment: Scipione, Can i ask you one more which somehow related to my problem here. I want to count the number of unique values of Week (say I need 3 week count of each product) but if it is less than 3, I would like to copy the previous week count and put zero count and change column name to 3rd week.

Comment: It's a little bit difficult to answer you in a comment, because I'm not sure I was able to figure out which is your desired output...maybe your question yet exists in SO. Whether it doesn't exist, try to formulate a new question and the SO community will help you.

Comment: Input 
 Product Week  Count
  <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
1 A       Wk1    2.00
2 B       Wk2    2.00
3 C       Wk3    1.00   
4 A       Wk1    3.00
5 B       Wk2    2.00   
6 C       Wk3    1.00   
7 A       Wk1    2.00   


Output

  <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
1 A       Wk1    2.00
2 B       Wk2    2.00
3 C       Wk3    1.00   
4 A       Wk1    3.00
5 B       Wk2    2.00   
6 C       Wk3    1.00   
7 A       Wk1    0   
8 B       Wk2    0 
9 C       Wk3    0                                 Here is input vs Output. Maybe it would help. I think the solution is close to this one too

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to add rows with zero counts for missing product-week combos:

```
# 0. attach dplyr for join, mutate, and magrittr pipe (%>%)
library(dplyr)

# 1. get the data as a data frame 
dat <- read.table(text="
Product   Week    Count
A         Wk1     2 
A         Wk2     2 
B         Wk1     3
C         Wk2     4
C         Wk3     3
", header=TRUE)

# 2. get unique products and unique weeks 
products <- unique(dat$Product)
weeks <- unique(dat$Week)

# 3.1 create a df with all combos of product and week 
expand.grid(Product=products, Week=weeks, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>%
  # 3.2 join it with original data (introduces NA counts for missing combos)
  left_join(dat, by=c("Product", "Week")) %>% 
  # 3.3 replace NA counts with zero 
  mutate(Count = ifelse(is.na(Count), 0, Count))
```

There's definitely other ways to do this, but this works (as long as you'll never have `NA` values in the original table).